# List all camera images in Android

Tags: android, camera, gallery, mediastore, android-contentresolver

How do you get a list of all camera images of an Android device?

Is it through the MediaStore? How?

Comment: This may help you http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e704c7c928dd2682

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Gallery app obtains camera images by using a [content resolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) over [Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) and filtering the results by [Media.BUCKET_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html#BUCKET_ID). The bucket identifier is determined with the following code:

```
public static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
        + "/DCIM/Camera";
public static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID =
        getBucketId(CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME);

/**
 * Matches code in MediaProvider.computeBucketValues. Should be a common
 * function.
 */
public static String getBucketId(String path) {
    return String.valueOf(path.toLowerCase().hashCode());
}
```

Based on that, here's a snippet to get all camera images:

```
public static List<String> getCameraImages(Context context) {
    final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = { CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID };
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            projection, 
            selection, 
            selectionArgs, 
            null);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            result.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

For more info, review the ImageManager and ImageList classes of the Gallery app source code.

Comment: Not all devices save the taken images/videos to "/DCIM/Camera". HTC desire HD, for example, saves to "/DCIM/100MEDIA"

Comment: And we should hate HTC Desire HD for that.

Comment: You can, however, just list all the files using File api instead of using DB cursors.

Comment: Can you please explain how to get the original image path from thumb? On this line: final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
 you get the path to the thumbnail image. I need, in my app, to display the thumbnail image (faster) and to save a copy of the image used to generate that thumbnail.

Comment: @hpique It's not just HTC devices that have different CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME strings. My Jelly Bean Galaxy Nexus returns just "Camera" for example.

Comment: links mentioned are broken

Comment: @dakait Links removed. I don't know where the Gallery source code is now. Any ideas?

Comment: nope did a quick search could find them :) if you are referring to stock gallery app them i think it must be somewhere https://github.com/android

Comment: @dakait According to github search they're not there.