# android - get images from camera shot

Tags: android, media, gallery, android-photos

I am curious as to how to get images from the Gallery/Camera folder in Android. I am looking into the file manager and can't really get a grasp as to where the those images are located in the file system. If I go to File Manager I can't locate the exact location of my taken photos. If I go to Gallery app I see them hanging in the "Camera" folder.

A little about what I am trying to accomplish:

Get all existing photos, saved at some point and display them on my activity. I am trying to allow the phone user to assign an avatar to their profile from existing photos.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all camera images in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484158/list-all-camera-images-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the code, in case somebody needs it. This is tested on gingerbread.

```
List<Image> existingPhotos = getCameraImages(this);

            photosGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvExistingPhotos);
            LazyPhotosGridAdapter adapter = new LazyPhotosGridAdapter(this, existingPhotos);
            photosGrid.setAdapter(adapter);





public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

        public static List<Image> getCameraImages(Context context) {
            final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = { CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID };
            final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                    projection, 
                    selection, 
                    selectionArgs, 
                    null);
            List<Image> result = new ArrayList<Image>(cursor.getCount());
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                do {
                    final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
                    result.add(new Image(data));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            return result;
        }

        public static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME =
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/DCIM/Camera";
        public static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID =
                getBucketId(CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME);

        /**
         * Matches code in MediaProvider.computeBucketValues. Should be a common
         * function.
         */
        public static String getBucketId(String path) {
            return String.valueOf(path.toLowerCase().hashCode());
        }
```

Comment: this is totally wrong, as are other similar answers. Not all phones save photos to a "/DCIM/Camera" folder. For example, Sony Xperia L uses "/DCIM/100ANDRO", and I guess that "100" part will increment sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484158/list-all-camera-images-in-android) might help. This is a common question, so you might get results if you searched StackOverflow for [Android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+camera).

Comment: ha, yes sorry I didn't realize its the same code. I found the same post few days ago :) Appreciate the help.