# android access gallery photos

Tags: android, image-uploading

Im trying to figure out how to access photos from the android default gallery and send them to my server.at the moment what my code is doing is user clicks the upload button then chooser comes and then he selects the photo and then i am sending the photo to the server. but what i want is the user clicks the upload button, all images from his gallery will be sent to the server without showing him the choice of any. you can say its much like a backup app.the user clicks backup images and all his images immediately sent to server. is that possible? how can i take all photos without giving him choice or chooser ?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484158/list-all-camera-images-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gallery by Default display all images which are stored in any folder
>   on phone. so you have to know URI of all images on phone and then read
>   and send these images to server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage custom Gallery and After that save All the file path which is selected by you/ user and pass them to server.

This link may help you to make custom gallery:

***[Custom Gallery](https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser)***